# Human-readable archive format for posting source examples?

Tags: archiving

Is there any package/archive format suitable for posting as source-code examples?

### Usecase

When posting minimal working examples, often a single file is enough. However, when a minimal working example consists of several files, things become messy, and notably any user trying to answer the question has to manually create several files. It would be convenient to have a format, that automatically creates an archive from a set of files, that can also be posted as human-readable MWE.

### Example how the format may look.

Using a latex example with a subfile as example. The theoretical tool would be invoked as `COMMAND -indent "    " main.tex includes/preamble.tex`, where the `-indent` toggle would add the required indentation for posting the file here.

```
****** main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\input{includes/preamble.tex}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}

****** includes/preamble.tex
\usepackage{lipsum}
```